# Error Make Responsive Design CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make my website to be responsive, so i using `@media (max-width:1600px){}` this code. I am making responsive design starting from the smallest width into the highest width.

so first i make responsive in 320 width:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
.w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
}
```

then in 360 width:

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
}
```

everything is going normal until i make responsive design in 800 width:

```
 @media (max-width: 800px) {
   .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 64px;
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: -100px;
}
}
```

The `h3` in 320 and 360 width will changing like in 800 width. but if i remove the `margin-left` in 800 width, then the `h3` in 320 and 360 width will be normal. please help any advice, if i should make responsive design starting from the higest width?

Comment: You need to specify min-width also in media rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're mentioning is that your `@media (max-width: 800px)` rule matches if the `window` width is ≤ 800px, meaning it applies while both the `320px` and `360px` rules also apply.

> These rules are applied in order from top to bottom; and a duplicate rule will override the previous rule.

#### Example

1. The `320px` selector will apply the `font-size`, `margin-top` and `line-height` rules
2. Then the `360px` selector will override these rules
3. Then the `800px` selector will override these rules and add the additional `margin` rules.

#### How to fix your issue

I'd suggest taking advantage of the css `and` operator to change your rules as follows -

```
@media (max-width : 360px) {

}

@media (min-width : 360px) and (max-width : 800px) {

}

@media (min-width : 800px) {

}
```

---

**Suggestion**:
If you're looking for a tried-and-tested example of *standard* media queries, try copying what Bootstrap 3 uses: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

> Extra small devices [Phones] (<768px)
>
> Small devices [Tablets] (≥768px)
>
> Medium devices [Desktops] (≥992px)
>
> Large devices [Desktops] (≥1200px)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `max-width`, then yes, use the highest width first. It all comes down to the fact that the parser takes the last rule it reads (that matches the specific media query).

Comment: so i have edit and make it responsive from the higest width? or any other way?

Comment: Placee the highest width at the top, decreasing to the lowest width at bottom (descending order)

Answer (score 1):

Put `max-width:800px`, after it `max-width:360px` and finally `max-width: 320px` as  Descending.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
    background-color: blue;
   }
} 

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
  background-color: green;
  }
}    
@media (max-width: 320px) {
.w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
   background-color: red
  }
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
    background-color: blue;
   }
} 

@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
  background-color: green;
  }
}    
@media (max-width: 360px) {
.w3l_banner_info1 h3 {
   background-color: red
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3l_banner_info1">
       <h3>This is Test</h3>
</div>
```

**Note:use full page and resize browser to see result.**